# MVC2 - Records in database not updating - No errors

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, crud

I'm having an odd little problem with MVC2. I am perorming some CRUD tasks, and I can Create records in the database just fine. But when I go to update a record with the following code nothing seems to happen to the database:

```
            EntityModelConnection entityModelConnection = new EntityModelConnection ();
            try {
            OrderLogic orderLogic= new OrderLogic ();

            EntityObject_Orders orderToUpdate = OrderLogic.GetOrderByID(1);
            orderToUpdate.Name = "Laptop";

            EntityModelConnection.SaveChanges(); }
```

My code isn't using names like these, they are just renamed for clarity :)

When I run over this code, no errors are thrown and the correct single record is returned from OrderLogic.GetOrdersByID, but nothing seems to update in the database.

It's a bit hard to find guides on this since most people are using UpdateModel in the controller and I'm doing my logic far from that location, so I can't (seem) to use that feature.

Any thoughts on what I might be missing? Is there something strange about MVC when it comes to updating records I might be missing?

I'm going for a coffee to refresh my brain :)

Comment: OrderLogic is a class that contains some LINQ statements (eg. GetOrderByProductName, GetOrderByPrice). In this case, it returns an EntityObject_Orders object by it's ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MVC or no MVC should have no effect on your data layer.  I suspect that your order isn't being updated because it either isn't marked as being changed in the persistance layer or you're not getting it from the same persistance layer object that you're saving changes in.  How is it that the connection you're creating and saving from is provided to the `OrderLogic` object to retrieve the `EntityObject_Orders` object?

Comment: dang it, I had a feeling it would be something silly like that... That works fine now! I wasn't aware that it had to use the same entity connection >_<  Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your Order instance came from a different entity connection.